# Chrome fires OnBlur again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

This is the code which fires Onblur again and again only in chrome, works fine in IE. In Firefox, the problem arises on creating two input elements... Can anyone please help me on this? I want the alert on blur *(in actual code we check for duplicates in a table and alert if duplicate is found, this code is just an example, demonstrating my need)* and after clicking on "OK" in alert box, I want to get the focus back.
Please see the right behavior in IE.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("div").append('<input type="text" name="txtCompanyName" maxlength="100" class="Company" style="margin-bottom:0px;width:170px"/>')
    });

    // With on():

    $("div").on("blur", ".Company", function() {
      alert($(this).text());
      $(".Company").focus();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div></div>
  <button>generate new element</button>

</body>

</html>
```

**Interesting thing-** when chrome starts firing event repetitively and you get bored of pressing "OK" again and again, then move to other tab in Chrome and then come back to this tab click on "OK", problem gets solved for that instance of blur. MAGIC??

Comment: You're creating an infinite loop by putting the focus back on the element which was blurred within the blur handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").on("blur", ".Company", function() {
  alert($(this).text());
  $(".Company").focus();
})
```

focus and blur are effectively opposites. so if your off focus (blur) you then set its focus back to Company, and Company is being appended to a div. so its looping indefinitely.